# Send Image to .PHP directly without using Base64

Tags: php, android

In the project I'm currently working for a company I need to send an image to a .php on a server which will save it on a folder and then send back the url so I can save it on a table from a DB.The company wants me to send the raw image instead of converting it to base64, send it and decode it on the .php file

My question is, Is this possible? and if so, how can I do it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am pretty sure if you do a search here in SO you will find many similiar answers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Check your php.ini and make sure this line is like this:

```
file_uploads = On
```

Create html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And creat upload.php file:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been     uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

To assure it all works, create a folder named uploads, and make sure file permissions and ownership are ok.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Note this code is from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)